# Are indexes using COLLATE LOCALIZED automatically rebuilt on locale change?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When Android locale is changed, do SQLite indices using `COLLATE LOCALIZED` have to be `REINDEX`ed explicitly or does this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no mechanism to detect changes in the definition of a collation sequence.
You have execute [REINDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html) manually.

Comment: Of course SQLite doesn't; if it were done automatically it would have to be done by Android which does know when the locale is changed. However, I guess Android doesn't know which databases have indices with `COLLATE LOCALIZED` (though it theoretically could).